# How do I create matrix in numpy to be called like this?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to learn Gradient descend from the internet and in the code it has something like this.

```
for i in range(len(points)):
   x = points[i].x
   y = points[i].y
```

However, I generate my dataset my self by

```
x = np.random.randint(10000, size=100000000)
y = x * 0.10
```

How do I create `points` with `x` and `y` to be able to fit into the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
x = np.random.randint(10000, size=100000000)
y = x * 0.10
np.column_stack((x,y))
```

This will use numpy optimisations for speed. More [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html)

and change code to this

```
for i in range(len(points)):
   x = points[i][0]
   y = points[i][1]
```

If you want `.x`, `.y` to work:
Use a class:

```
class point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
#[OR]

import collections
Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])


#and then

for i in range(len(x)):
    points.append(point(x[i],y[i]))
```

This would perform slower

Comment: Can you change p(x[i], y[i]) to points(x[i], y[i]) in the last line. I tried suggesting an edit, but SO doesn't accept one less than six characters.

Comment: You could also use a `namedtuple` for point.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing its a class. You can make a dummy class as follows

```
import numpy as np
class p:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y


points = []
x = np.random.randint(10000, size=100000000)
y = x * 0.10
for i in range(len(x)):
    points.append(p(x[i],y[i]))

for i in range(len(points)):
   x = points[i].x
   y = points[i].y
```

This is probably quite inefficient though. But if you want the same interface to work, this should be good enough.